# Convert byte[] with negative value to String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have this byte[] = {-53, 54, -5, -89, -69, -126, -57, 36, 49, 114, -66, 67, 39, 18, 57, -40, 50, -113, 52, -113, 111, -65, -20, -127, -84, 90, -74, -47, 94, 23, 18, -36}

How can I convert it to String? I've tried many ways to do, but all of them do not work

I'm using this library to encode my string https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android, there are some line of code to genarate the byte[] above

```
private static SecretKeySpec generateKey(final String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_ALGORITHM);
    byte[] bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    byte[] key = digest.digest(); //I want to convert this byte[] to String

    log("SHA-256 key ", key);

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    return secretKeySpec;
}
```

Comment: `new String(key, theCharSet)`. But note that you can't convert all byte sequences into valid strings in all charsets.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried, but the String I received is ����

Comment: see my "but note". You get the `�` when you try to convert an invalid byte sequence.

Comment: so we dont have any way to convert it? T_T

Comment: "when you try to convert an invalid byte sequence." -> why I recieved an invalid byte  sequence?

Comment: it's an invalid sequence of bytes *with respect to a particular charset*. For example, not all byte sequences are valid in UTF-8, whereas they are in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @AndyTurner Or it could be that the console that the OP is using can't print that specific character.

Comment: @QkLahpita "so we dont have any way to convert it?" you do; but you need to understand that "converting bytes to a string" is not a well-defined operation in and of itself. The same bytes can convert to many different strings.

Comment: @assylias also true.

Comment: I think what you want to do is `base64` encode your byte array: `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should encode your byte array using Base64.

If you use Java8, Base64 is already included in java.util package.

Try the following code:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        byte[] b = {-53, 54, -5, -89, -69, -126, -57, 36, 49, 114, -66, 67, 39, 18, 57, -40, 50, -113, 52, -113, 111, -65, -20, -127, -84, 90, -74, -47, 94, 23, 18, -36};
         String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b);
         System.out.println(encoded);

    }
```

Result:

```
  yzb7p7uCxyQxcr5DJxI52DKPNI9vv+yBrFq20V4XEtw=
```